# Sum hours/minutes that fall within a certain month

Tags: excel

I am trying to sum all hours/minutes that fall within a certain month (January to begin with). The function I currently have is returning 0:00:00. This is the formula:

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B262, A2:A262, ">=01/01/2021", A2:A262, "<=31/01/2021")
```

This is **part** of the table:

[image]

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: Have you checked that the dates are formatted as dates and not as text? If they are formatted as text, the evaluation won't be working.

Comment: Thanks Sam. I'll take a look tomorrow when I'm back at my desk and let you know how I get on

Comment: The dates are definitely formatted as dates and the hours/minutes column is formatted as time

Comment: Just to make sure, can you select column A, go to Data tab -> Text to Columns -> (Step 1) Next -> (Step 2) Next -> (Step 3) Select Date format and then Finish. If it isn't an issue with the data type then unfortunately I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: Thanks again for your response Sam. Yeah I've tried that and it's still not working unfortunately. I have recreated the scenario on a different computer using exactly the same data type and formula and this works. Makes me think that it's something to do with the settings on excel...

Comment: From the screenshot, I can only see up to row 41, not all the way to 262, so I can't check if there is another row after 41 that contains a date in January. I doubt there is, but for example if there is one other January date between row 41 and 262 and the hours for it says `08:00:00` then the calculation would indeed result in `00:00:00`.

Comment: I guess another thing to test is change the formula to `=SUMIFS(B2:B10, A2:A10, ">=01/01/2021", A2:A10, "<=31/01/2021")` just to see if that results in anything different.

Comment: It's something to do with the values in the hours/minutes column as even when I use the formula =SUM(B2:B262) it is returning 0:00:00. There are no other dates within January in the rest of the column either

Comment: What does `=SUM(B2:B3)` return?

Comment: it returns 0:00:00

Comment: This is data that has been pulled from a workforce management tool called EWFM. I am wondering if something weird is happening to the data/values when It's converted to excel data as when I try and change the format of the data to 'custom' - [h]:mm:ss, it doesn't convert the value from say 79:30 to 79:30:00, it just leaves it as 79:30

Comment: Then your times are stored as text and not true times.  You will need to convert them to true times.