# Time showing as 02/01/1900 when clicking on cell

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, format, worksheet-function

I have a cell that is where the data type is 'custom' and then [h]:mm:ss. The value in the cell is 66:33:00. When clicking on the cell, the formula bar in Excel shows the value as: 02/01/1900 18:30:00.

I am unable to use functions such as SUM or SUMIFS on this cell as the value keeps returning 0:00:00.

What's the reason this?

Comment: That should not affect using SUM. (Excel stores date/time values as numbers starting at 1/1/1900 which is why you are seeing that date in the formula bar)

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirming this. I've got an issue where a hours/minutes column is not allowing me to SUM it's values and I wasn't sure if this was the cause. See my other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65222257/sum-hours-minutes-that-fall-within-a-certain-month

Answer (score 0):

You should not use 66:33:00 in SUMIFS. Because this value is only for your eyes. The Excel can work with true value only, i.e. 02/01/1900 18:30:00.